# How to stop reindexing in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've started reindexing some of my data from one index to another using the Reindex API. The problem is that now I want to stop the reindexing process, even though it has not finished. I'm able to see the process running with this command:

```
GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex
```

But, how can I stop it?

EDIT: Stopping the whole cluster is not a possibility because it is being used for other purposes at the same time.

Comment: will restarting cluster works??

Comment: Not a possibility, cause the cluster is being used for other purposes and can't be stopped. But thanks anyway. @PandiyanCool

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [Cancel Task API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html#task-cancellation) if the Task is `cancellable`

[Quoting from documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api)

> Any Reindex can be canceled using the Task Cancel API:
>
> ```
> POST _tasks/node_id:task_id/_cancel
> ```
>
> The task_id can be found using the Tasks API.
>
> Cancelation should happen quickly but might take a few seconds. The
>   Tasks API will continue to list the task until it wakes to cancel
>   itself.

---

Using the command below, get the task ID and follow

```
GET _tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex
```

Use the **`id`** given out from the command and cancel using the Task API

```
 "tasks" : {
    "r1A2WoRbTwKZ516z6NEs5A:36619" : {
      "node" : "r1A2WoRbTwKZ516z6NEs5A",
      "id" : 36619,
      "type" : "transport",
      "action" : "indices:data/write/reindex",
      .....
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but I needed both the node id and the task id. The solution looks more like "POST _tasks/node_id:task_id/_cancel"

Comment: I used this to get the nid/tid, but check your output before you use it! `curl -s "http://localhost:9200/_tasks?actions=*reindex&format=yaml" | awk -F: 'NF>2 && /:$/ { sub(/:$/,"") ; sub(/^[ \t]+/,"") ; print $0 }'`

Answer (score 3):

This is the one that worked for me.

`POST _tasks/_cancel?nodes=node_id&actions=*reindex`